# Java, JSON, need to get an array (or collection) of objects

Tags: java, json

The JSON document has the following format:

```
[{"category":{"id":123, "name": "Some Category", "type": "some type"}},
{"category":{"id":234, "name": "Another Category", "type": "some type"}},
{"category":{"id":345, "name": "New Category", "type": "other type"}}]
```

I plan to create the Category class (with "id", "name", "type" fields) and use GSon or FasterXML to parse this JSON and get an array (or a collection) of Category objects.

Is it possible?

Does anyone have a recipe for this case - when the items are NOT immediately at the top level in JSON but "nested" as in the example above?

Comment: Yes, it's possible! Think you should try to google a little first!

Comment: I did it first. I'm not that stupid.

Comment: ok, post your code. What have you tried?

Comment: I already changed the code that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
String jsonString = ... // my JSON as a String
List<Category> Categories = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
int n = array.length();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  JSONObject wrapperObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONObject obj = wrapperObj.getJSONObject("category");
  Category category = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), Category.class);
  Categories.add(category);
}
```